# fakechroot-like functionality in MacOS?

Tags: osx, chroot, fakechroot

I want to use a `chroot` approach when building executables in MacOS, for having great control of the files and libraries they use. Ideally maybe `chroot` would be enough (and it is available in MacOS), but, first of all I think it requires the user to be root when running it, and second, I looked at the functionality offered by `fakechroot` and it looks more interesting than `chroot` for my purposes (however, `fakechroot` is not ported to MacOS).

In particular, `fakechroot` looks like the way I want to follow, because it replaces functions such as `open()` and by replacing `open()` I could have a great degree of control on the "virtual environment" that I create for the executables. For example, instead of copying required system libs in the `chroot` tree, my patched `open()` could provide access to only the libraries I wish the executable to use.

Is there something like this already available for MacOS? Or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm wondering if such a tool exists as well, and the current answer by thrig to use App Sandbox does not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

[App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) is perhaps more suitable than trying to port third-party code, as it operates in the kernel and is supported by Apple; quoting from the link:

> By limiting access to sensitive resources on a per-app basis, App
>   Sandbox provides a last line of defense against the theft, corruption,
>   or deletion of user data, or the hijacking of system hardware, if an
>   attacker successfully exploits security holes in your app. For
>   example, a sandboxed app must explicitly state its intent to use any
>   of the following resources using entitlements:
>
> ...
>
> On the other hand, a sandboxed app has access to the specific
>   resources you request, allows users to expand the sandbox by
>   performing typical actions in the usual way (such as drag and drop),
>   and can automatically perform many additional actions deemed safe ...

Comment: Are you sure you can limit filesystem read access with `App Sandbox` ? Searching the docs I find settings for disabling write access, but not read access (and I need to disable read access, in order to force the use of only the desired set of dynamic libraries)

Comment: what docs were you reading? "App Sandbox Design Guide" talks about various filesystem access knobs, and "Entitlement Key Reference" shows various settings that can go into the entitlements, and a quick trip through the Xcode tutorial shows "read" vs. "r/w" vs. "write-only" options for various filesystem entitlements.

Comment: That document says that _"In addition, the system automatically permits a sandboxed app to: [...] Read files that are world readable, in certain directories, including the following directories: /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/lib..."_ and those are precisely the directories whose access I want to limit. I have the impression that **App Sandbox** has the opposite goal than the solution I need: I want isolation from the system directories while not caring about non-system directories. And  **App Sandbox** is the opposite: isolation from non-system directories, while not caring about system directories